# How to produce xml tag with attributes using PyRssGen?

Tags: python, rss

I've created an Rss with PyRssGen this way:

```
rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
        title="Web news feed",
        link="http://www.web.com",
        description="Web social trending news",
        items=[
            PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem
            (
            guid=PyRSS2Gen.Guid(str("LINK"), isPermaLink=False),
            title =  "TITLE",
            author =  "REpublishan",
            link= "LINK",
            pubDate= datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 6, 21, 49),
            description= "DESCRIPTION",
            # enclosure="",
            )
            ]
    )
```

But I don't know how to produce enclosure tag like this:

```
<enclosure url="http://Web.com/image/get/2014-07-18_15_5901405697460470_big.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="0"/>
```

I need to have 3 attributes in an item. Do you have any idea?